# Without domain how to install sharepoint 2016 in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I new in sharepoint, stuck on sharepoint installation process with out domain.My pc is in workgroup so i use the bellow script for create the db,But it's show me error.Need help how to solve this script error.

**Script**

```
New-SPConfigurationDatabase –DatabaseName SharePoint16_Config –DatabaseServer TEST_SERVER\MSSQLSERVER2014 –AdministrationContentDatabaseName SharePoint16_Content –Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString 786@r!5t0c## –AsPlaintext –Force) –FarmCredentials (Get-Credential) -localserverrole SingleServerFarm
```

[image]

**Script error**

[image]

What should i do? how to solve this script error?

Answer (score 1):

you have to type this command :

psconfig.exe -cmd configdb -create -server sp2016-local -database SharePoint_Config -user Administrator -password `YOUR password !!` -passphrase P@ssw0rd -admincontentdatabase SharePoint_AdminContent -localserverrole SingleServerFarm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcleM.png)

after that you should have like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqb7t.png)

and you can now Use the Start Screen of the server, type "SharePoint" to locate the SharePoint Products Wizard and launch it. The wizard detects the Farm we have just created.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0XRF.png)

If you have followed this tutorial carefully and named the computer as I did, the only diference between your command line and mine is the Administrator account pasword. If your server name is different you will have also to update the server name.

Answer (score 0):

You can see here in the blog post that SharePoint 2016 installation on a environment with Workgroup and no Active Directory is not supported:

[What’s new in SharePoint Server 2016 Installation and Deployment](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2015/05/12/whats-new-in-sharepoint-server-2016-installation-and-deployment/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try specify username in format `MachineName\UserName` in your case `TEST_SERVER\Administrator`.